# Update field from one table to another if exist, else null

Tags: ms-access, foreign-keys, ado.net, relational-database

I have two tables(Columns) `Employee(ID, EmployeeName, FK_DepartmentID)` And `Department(ID, DepartmentName)` where my `Employee` table holds the Data of employee and set the foreign key of the department. [Relational DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUlle.jpg) [Department Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrBAu.jpg) [Employee Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5DFK.jpg)

Now in my VB Code where I have an Employee Name textbox, and a combobox for the department from where users can update the Employee name and department. So I want to update Employee Table's Name as well as Foreign Key of the department so I used:

```
UPDATE Employee e, (SELECT d.ID FROM Department d Where d.DepartmentName = @dept) As d 
SET e.FK_Department = d.ID, e.EmployeeName = @name
WHERE ((e.ID)='3') ;
```

Which seems to work fine. But I want my combobox of the department to be optional. Where It can be not selected and if so the `FK_Department` in `Employee` table will be NULL. But if I run the query without any value for @dept, the query creates 0 new rows which make sense, as my `(SELECT d.ID FROM Department d Where d.DepartmentName = @dept)` returns nothing. What can I do to update the query to get the result?

I also have tried joining but not sure where to apply `Where d.DpartmentName = @dept`, tried `Set e.FK_Department = IIF((Select ID From Department Where DepartmentName = @dept) Is Null, Null, Department.ID)`, but seems not working.

Side note: Not sure if my problem is Upsert. Because at the end I am updating Employee Table nevertheless, Or my thinking is wrong?

Your assistance would be life-saving if it's possible. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this VB or VBA? Add appropriate tag. If Department ID is not provided then don't build SQL that is dependent on it. Use conditional code to build valid SQL.

Comment: It is VB, I need the query which I was trying to build in MS-access. So you are saying it's not possible from the query but I have to build the query string conditionally?

Comment: As I said, edit tags for programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Use sub query as follows:

```
UPDATE Employee e
   Set e.EmployeeName = @name,
       e.FK_Department = coalesce((select d.ID FROM Department d Where d.DepartmentName = @dept),
                                  e.FK_Department)
WHERE e.ID='3' ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Getting Undefined function 'coalesce' in expression error. Although tried with NZ in access, still getting the error "Operation must use an updateable query".